# Can I use Google Drive to host Facebook app?

Tags: hosting, google-drive-api, facebook-apps

I am trying to build a small experiment app for Facebook. And as it consists only of static files, I decided to try using Google Drive for hosting. As soon as I wrote Google Drive address to Facebook canvas, I tried to launch the app. What I got was a white screen and two error messages in Chrome js console:

> https://googledrive.com/host/myWebViewLink/ POST 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> https://googledrive.com/host/myWebViewLink/:1 Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

I tried to launch the app in iframe in a different website, and it worked fine, so probably the error is not in Google Drive iframe restrictions.

Also I tried to link a webpage not hosted in google drive to Facebook canvas, and it again worked for me, so probably the error is not in app configuration.

Could you please help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the Facebook [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) reach the URL?

Comment: It can (Response Code: 200), however there are some OpenGraph warnings, like "'og:url' property should be explicitly provided" - not sure if it's relevant

Comment: probably not, but the debugger is a great way to tell if Facebook has access to a URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check the links you provided in your question, because they are invalid (*404 not found*).

As for *405 method not allowed*, you can check yourself using [web sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=https://googledrive.com/host/0BzEbtMoF6IXbaVN2Qmx1em9qS0k/&gzip=yes&http=1.1&type=POST) that google Drive doesn't support the POST method, only HEAD and GET.

As for *X-Frame-Options*, Google Drive doesn't show this header with GET requests, so you can put them in frames, like on [GDrives](http://gdriv.es).

Comment: that's because I made dumb links :) I tried to check GDrive, and warping my webview with it seems to work for http (solves both issues), but not for https. I already wrote my own warping in GAE, that is not an elegant but a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! However, GDrives should work over https too: [example](https://gdriv.es/cros/download.html)