# google drive hosting changes in URL

Tags: google-drive-api

I've developed a web app that uses google drive as hosting platform as explained here:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

The application has been working OK when users accessed:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B0YWdwxH6K5XdVpaNjhWUl9vZkE/?scriptid=AKfycbx66sZMaqLK8byhV7wY_DoQ8ouqF1acWRcc0JIHyDu5CVWZupAK&id=people

But yesterday it started redirecting that address to:

b216bdb4cf56e8d9d85cf1123921ca125a010325.googledrive.com/host/0B0YWdwxH6K5XdVpaNjhWUl9vZkE/

any idea why? is this a permanent change? does the subdomain key follow any logic?

Browser: occurs on chrome & IE
Operating System: windows8
Drive on the Web / Drive for desktop: when accessing googledrive.com/host

Comment: No longer supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working/40478448#40478448

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive CSS Returns 404 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-css-returns-404-error)

Answer (score 1):

I found the right thread at google.com to answer this. Here it is: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/mTyJXruRhBg

In short, the redirect and prefix is here to stay. It's for some security thing. All files within the same googledrive folder will be prefixed with the same guid-looking string. That is, provided we use this googledrive url form: googledrive.com/host/{folderID}/FriendlyFilename. Then, any support files you want to access or link from that folder, just access them as FriendlyFilename with relative url form.

My problem was, I was using the obscure form googledrive.com/host/{userID+fileID}. (no FolderID or FriendlyFilename). That now gets a different domain prefix for every file within the same folder.

Here's a different variation of that test file I showed above (which was getting Security exception for webworker). It works now by using the {FolderID}/FriendlyFilename form. Tada. https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XME1rNU9iWnYtbTg/ded-worker-F12throw.html

Comment: No longer supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working/40478448#40478448