# libjass on Google Drive Host, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I would like to use [libjass](https://github.com/Arnavion/libjass) with video-js on Google Drive Host.

But Google Drive Host allows only HTML and JS files, I can’t install Node on Google Drive. So how can I use libjass on Google Drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow `README.md`, you’ll get to the [„I want to use libjass for my website. What do I need to do?“](https://github.com/Arnavion/libjass/blob/master/README.md#i-want-to-use-libjass-for-my-website-what-do-i-need-to-do) part.

> 1. You need to build libjass.js using the instructions in BUILD.md
> 2. You need to load libjass.js and libjass.css on the page with your video.
> 3. You need to call the libjass API.
>
> Only libjass.js and libjass.css are needed to use libjass on your website. The other files are only used during the build process and you don't need to deploy them to your website.

Then reading [`BUILD.md`](https://github.com/Arnavion/libjass/blob/master/BUILD.md):

> 1. Install node.js from http://nodejs.org/ or via your package manager
> 2. Change to the directory where you cloned this repository.
> 3. Run the following command
>
>    npm install
>
>    This will install the dependencies - [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/), [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) and [Vinyl](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl). It will then run gulp to build libjass.js and minify it into libjass.min.js

So just build it locally on your computer and upload just the already built .js files to your Google Drive.