# google drive hosted images were loading slowly when compared to images hosted on my server

Tags: image, google-drive-api

I am uploading all my images to google drive and embedding them in my site with their id like this https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B8-NsDn0E-3ad04wSFVrOEJXVDg, but these were redirecting  to some url like this https://doc-0g-88-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ge7mqn64591151duj3pjmk1qd5rpmkt0/8pqhasfepbv535873kqi6fmjvos892pe/1422460800000/04036438152152126414/13724322124206961204/0B8-NsDn0E-3ad04wSFVrOEJXVDg, this causes loading slow in my site when compared to other images which hosted on my server. Is this common to load slowly or else i have to get this redirected full path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i'm totally grasping this, but it would definitely make sense that loading images would be slower hosted from a google drive account than from your site, for a few reasons:

1. when your server is hosting the images, the browser/server could make use of the already-established credentials (if you require a login), and the image lookup could be (arguably negligibly) faster on your server
2. if your google drive hosting requires authentication (which i'm pretty sure it does), that is substantial overhead for each image (though this could also be cached by the server/browser)
3. a redirect causes more overhead, since an HTTP GET request must be performed for each redirect, until it reaches the url where the image resource is being "hosted" (i know i'm being pretty loose with my terminology)
4. google is performing bookkeeping behind the scenes to track your bandwidth, accesses per minute/hour/month/whatever, either to bill you, or to generate ad revenue; this bookkeeping costs computer cycles which, if you're pulling a lot of images from their storage, could add up
5. if you're talking about actually downloading an image, versus finding one, that could also be true: google could be throttling the speed, if it's a free account, to encourage you to pay for some other storage

not sure that answers your question, but it's a few ideas.