# Direct linking to a Google Drive hosted file in preview mode

Tags: google-drive-api, file-permissions

I'm trying to link directly to a Google Drive file that is publicly available with (anyone, and reader) set as permissions and with no value set. This should make the doc publicly available on the internet.

The link I'm using to access the file is:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=FILD-ID&usp=sharing

The problem is this link takes the user to a listing of the file which requires another click to preview it.

How do I link directly to the previewer in Google Drive?

Comment: you are using a folder link. use the file link.

Comment: I tried that as well but get a "No preview available". This is the link I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE-ID/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)