# Website hosting on google drive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with my website. I had created it with bootstrap 3 and I published it on google drive for free.

The design of the page is not the same as it is when I was designing it.

This is the link to the website.

https://ad4a25dbdfc20e86e4f693c23065e49b8d4085f3.googledrive.com/host/0B-vW4Ptl6ojISmttTS1Fc2RjTDQ/

[this is the image of the website before hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG5fD.jpg). The contents should be centered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the head.
All external files must be linked with https:// instead of http:// otherwise it will be blocked by the browser.

You can check Google Chromes Developer Tools for errors.

Cheers

Comment: oKAY...LET ME SEE THEN I WILL TELL YOU HOW IT IS

Comment: @sospetermong'are Did you have any luck fixing the problem?

Comment: i was able to correct. the problem was with http instead of https. but i am having problem again. the website is not viewing welll in opera mini for mobile..